# How reliable is a second hand 2011 bmw 335i?

Tags: bmw

not sure if this is the forum to ask this sort of question...

I'm thinking of buying a 2011 bwm 335i with 16K KM on it.  What sort of issues do these cars have normally?  Should I stay away from this one, I'm just worried that I get it and turns out to be a lot of work afterwards.

Comment: The problem with shopping advice is that it does not lend itself well to a [definitive answer](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  However, we do have a chatroom that is excellent for this sort of [open-ended discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair).

Comment: I usually use [CarComplaints.com](http://www.carcomplaints.com/BMW/) for secondhand car research. Unfortunately, the 335i doesn't seem to have very much information. Although that can mean it's either a very good car, or BMW didn't sell very many of that model. (I have no affiliation with the website.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Don't buy expensive exotics secondhand because maintenance costs will kill you.

BMW's are usually pretty reliable, but I wouldn't buy one with 16 000km on the odometer. My reasoning is that it was probably returned because there was something wrong with it. Or it's been driven by an old man who never went over 40km/h and thus ruined the engine (lots of boring reasons like not getting hot enough to evaporate water and thus causing rust in the engine, etc) It's also a very expensive car to maintain when the service plan and/or warranty expires, which I guess it has seeing as it's a 3 year old model.

Make no mistake, it's an awesome car to drive but I don't think the maintenance costs are quite worth it. I'd rather spend a bit more on an M3. Or otherwise opt for a 325i or an Audi A4 2.0 Turbo of the same year. They're almost the same performance- and luxury-wise, but at a fraction of the maintenance costs. You won't believe how much extra it costs to maintain those two extra cylinders in the 335i.